# How to transfer the number to the API? vue js, Web API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When sent to API. A string is sent, but a number should be. How to fix?
Discount: "40"

Sorry for the stupid question.

Here is the object vue js.

```
  reg:{
  username:"",
  password:"",
  Discount:0},


<td> <select type = "number" placeholder="Discount" v-model="reg.Discount">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>10</option>
 </select></td>
```

Comment: What API ? What does the documentation says ? How to you send the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.number` modifier

```
<td> <select type = "number" placeholder="Discount" v-model.number="reg.Discount">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>10</option>
 </select></td>
```

Comment: New problem.
When it changes.
If so.
The data on the form is displayed.
<td> <select type = "number" placeholder="Discount" v-model="clickedUser.discount">
But they are not saved.

Comment: Does not help.  use .number modifier

Comment: what is not saved ? is `reg.Discount` reactive ?

Comment: The API accepts a number. Sent as a string.

Comment: what is output of `typeof reg.Discount` ?

Comment: Understood. The answer is correct.
I'll post some code. Can someone help.
v-model.number="clickedProduct.price"